# Dispatch Group notify placement?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I've been messing around with dispatch groups and am wondering how the placement of the notify callback of a dispatch group affects when the callback will be called. I'm reading data from my database and then fetching a picture for each item in the data that was read. When I have the notify outside of the initial database read block I notice it gets called immediately, however when the notify is inside the block it behaves the proper way. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("invites")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for child in snapshots {
                    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
                    let info = petInfo(petName: child.value! as! String, dbName: child.key)
                    print(info)
                    self.invitesData[info] = UIImage()
                    let picRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(info.dbName+".png")
                    picRef.data(withMaxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error getting picture")
                        }
                        // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
                        self.invitesData[info] = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
                self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
                    print("YOOO")
                    self.invitesArray = Array(self.invitesData.keys)
                    print(self.invitesArray)
                    self.inviteTable.reloadData()
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

This code behaves properly when the notify is within the original database read block. However if I place this after the `ref.observeSingleEvent` block the notify gets called immediately.

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: If you have it outside the block then the notify gets reached before any of your calls to `self.dispatchGroup.enter()` are reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Asynchronous code :-)

Code execution runs all the way through to the end of the function, and **then** the completion handler will be called